# How can I ensure the safety of my new business?

Tags: business

I purchased a domain for a to be mobile application and website creation business.

I'm an application developer and not a business professional I am aware there could potentially be taxes and unwanted side effects like somebody buying the business name which i havent even done yet i just need a rundown on what steps i need to take to not get unexpectedly screwed over in the future, like getting taxed for some loophole.

Comment: That's the job of your lawyer/accountant.

Comment: I feel like your question is too broad, for us to list of all the steps of owning a business, could you ask a more specific question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about startup business practice, not The Workplace.

Comment: What country are you in?

Answer (score 5):

> How can I ensure the safety of my new business?

Hire a good accountant. Hire a good lawyer. If you need more help, connect with a good life coach or mentor. Develop a strong, deep professional network. Work hard.

Comment: This is good advice but I recommend making sure you're actually profiting before spending monies on lawyers and accountants. Otherwise you're only getting them to profit.